# Changing CSS depending on JSDiff in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-state

Does anyone know how to implementing JSDiff color change in React?

Everything seems to be working fine regarding the console log, it throws the correct response, I'm stuck understanding how to use colors now

```
  const compareEnvs = (e) => {

    let envContent = some values;
    let envContent2 = some other values;

    const diff = Diff.diffChars(envContent, envContent2)
    diff.forEach((part) => {
      const color = part.added ? "green" : part.removed ? "red" : "grey";
    });
    console.log(diff)
  };
```

console.log(color) < example

```
red
green
gray 
red
green
green 
etc...
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'using the colors'? Do you want to render multiple colors on the page using a loop? Do you want to have a single color state that updates depending on the diff? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I wanted to use css property as change the color of divs based on color. Yet, I went a bit of a different way this is not an issue anymore, thank you